# Please explain why my mp3 file won't play

Tags: html, audio

I'm watching a Youtube video to learn HTML and CSS.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cyuzt1Dp8X8&t=5566s

I downloaded an mp3 file to my computer, but when I run my code, the audio file doesn't play.  In my HTML code, I used the name of the audio file rather than the path.  I know the name of the mp3 file is correct.  However, by using the path rather than the file name, I have been able to play the audio in my browser.  Again, the first code will NOT play the audio file, but the second code will play the audio file.

```
<audio controls>
<source src="CouldItBeKP.mp3" />
</audio>

<audio controls>
<source src="C:\Users\james\Downloads\CouldItBeKP.mp3" />
</audio>
```

Also, the author of the Youtube video believes the location of the audio file matters.  For example, the audio file won't play if I move the mp3 file from Desktop to Downloads or vice versa.  The code is below.

```
<audio controls>
<source src="CouldItBeKP.mp3" />
</audio>
```

Please help!  Thanks.

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<source>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-source-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: You seem to already have answered your own question: If the second version works, it's a matter of the filepath. Obviously your mp3 file is not in the same directory as your HTML file, but in the "Downloads" folder you specified in the second version. So what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you do not specify the full path, most browsers will assume that the file is in the same folder. So if your code was in `~\Documents`, but the audio was in `~\Downloads`, it would not play. If they were both in `~\Documents`, it would play.

Answer (score 0):

You need the path to be correct, without the path it greys out. Put it in your main directory and try ./CouldItBeKP.mp3

Answer (score 0):

it seems like your audio files are on the downloads folder, but I'm not sure where your code is.
I would suggest you move your audio files and your codes to the same directory.

For example, if my HTML file is in
`C:\Users\james\project`
My music files also should be also in `C:\Users\james\project` or somewhere near this folder. Eg: `C:\Users\james\project\music`

Now, let's assume, my music files are inside `C:\Users\james\project\music` while my HTML file is in `C:\Users\james\project`

So, my code for playing the music would be like this.

```
<audio controls>
<source src="music/CouldItBeKP.mp3" />
</audio>
```

Or

```
<audio controls>
<source src="./music/CouldItBeKP.mp3" />
</audio>
```

`./` means to start from the current folder. In our case, which is `C:\Users\james\project`

Then your second code will also play the audio.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
type="audio/mpeg"
```